# Understand %03.3u in printf format specification

Tags: c++, c, printf

I am using printf to output contents. Now I see the format specification as "%03.3u" in another person's code, as per my understanding the "03" before the dot already specifies the width of the output as 3 digits, and padding with zeros if there are not 3, while the "3" after the dot also specifies that there should be 3 digits output. Therefore, it seems "03" before the dot and "3" after the dot is duplicated.

I make the following tests:

```
    char l[50];

    sprintf(l, "%03.3u", 5);
    sprintf(l, "%03u", 5);
    sprintf(l, "%.3u", 5);
```

And confirm the output is always 005. So why someone else should use "%03.3u" instead of "%03u" or "%.3u"?

Comment: `%.3u` and `%03u` are equivalent.  The [rationale for the C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) says that it prefers the `.` notation to the `0` flag — but the flag isn't going away because it is used far too widely.  The composite `%03.3u` combines two equivalent notations — and gives the same result.

Comment: The reference is on p152 of the PDF file: _The use of leading zero in field widths to specify zero padding is superseded by a precision field.
The older mechanism was retained._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output will be the same for the particular *values* you have used. The number before the `.` is the minimum *field width* while the number after (for the `u` conversion specifier, at least) it is the minimum number of *digits* to output. You can see the difference between the two with something like:

```
printf("%3.2u\n", 7)
```

which gives you `space07` - minimum two digits output and minimum three characters wide.

However, the fact that you have the numbers the same means that you'll get three digits minimum in a field at least three characters wide. Even if you had used `%03.2u` (different minimums), the presence of that `0` means to left-pad with `0` rather than `space`, so you'd *still* see `005`.

---

Bottom line is, to get the full three digits, you can use the `0` zero-pad modifier *or* the minimum digit count modifier but you don't need *both.*

However, since having both doesn't have any adverse effects beyond forcing people to question the sanity of those that wrote it :-), it's *functionally* okay.

Answer (score 2):

The `03` is the *field width* with zero-padding. This means that a minimum of 3 **characters** are to be output, and if there were fewer than three, left-pad with zeroes.

The second `3` is the minimum number of **digits** to output.

When both of these are specified, the precision will be applied, and if the result is narrower than the minimum field width, then the output will be padded. For example`printf("q%6.3u", 5)` will produce `q   005` .  (I use the `q` because stackoverflow formatting eats the spaces otherwise).

If you're printing an unsigned integer and you didn't use the sign flag,  then the number of digits is the same as the field width (since the only output is digits).  `%03u`, `%.3u` and `%03.3u` all have the same effect.

I guess the person wrote `%03.3u` since they did not properly understand the meaning of these things so they guessed something, it worked, and they decided to not make any further changes.

If you print a sign character then the field width differs from the digit count, e.g. you could experiment with `%+3u` versus `%+.3u`. Or if you use `%d` and print a negative number.